# Avoid Replacing DHCP-discovered DNS Resolvers?

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq, networkmanager

I am on CentOS 7.4 attempting to configure dnsmasq for DNS caching and per-zone DNS servers for running Consul. Essentially, the dnsmasq configuration boils down to this:

```
# filter everything with consul in the name and send to local consul resolver
server=/consul/127.0.0.1#8600
```

The problem I'm having is getting the local resolver into `/etc/resolv.conf` without replacing any other resolvers in the file.

I used to be able to do this using `dhclient` configuration like so:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

Since everything is NetworkManager now, I have discovered that the way to use dnsmasq is to add the following line to the `[main]` section of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

Before restarting NetworkManager, I see that my `/etc/resolv.conf` contains the network DNS server received by DCHP:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search nowhere
nameserver 10.0.2.3
options single-request-reopen
```

Upon restarting NetworkManager with the above configuration change, it supersedes my network DNS server with 127.0.0.1:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search nowhere
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options single-request-reopen
```

Since dnsmasq uses the `/etc/resolv.conf` to detect local resolvers, I'd like to leave the resolver(s) in `/etc/resolv.conf` so that dnsmasq can discover them.

Is there a way to achieve the previous functionality of having NetworkManager just prepend the local resolver instead?

Comment: Is there anything compelling you to keep NetworkManager?  Simple and painless to 'yum remove' it.  (I'm intentionally avoiding debate on how useful it is on a server system)

Comment: `dnsmasq uses the /etc/resolv.conf` - It doesn't have to.  It can be configured to use a different file.  And you can configure your DHCP client to write the DHCP options to a different file.  This is what happens on recent Debian-based systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently even though CentOS 7.4 does not ship with an upstream `/etc/dhclient.conf`, this is still a valid path. I simply created this file with the following contents:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

And voila!

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search nowhere
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 10.0.2.3
options single-request-reopen
```